# Beamer referencing parts, chapters, sections, and subsections

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, chapters, parts, subsection

I try to reference correctly `part`, `chapter`, `section`, and `subsection` in a beamer presentation.

The code is:

```
\documentclass[envcountsect,10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{chngcntr,xcolor,bbm,placeins,float,latexsym,amsxtra,amssymb,amsbsy,amsthm,amscd,amsfonts,amsmath,subcaption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{figure}{section}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}

\usetheme{Antibes}
\AtBeginPart{\frame{\partpage}}
\AtBeginSection{\frame{\sectionpage}}
\AtBeginSubsection{\frame{\subsectionpage}}

\setbeamertemplate{part page}
{
  \begin{centering}
    {\usebeamerfont{part name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{part name}\partname~\insertpartnumber}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=16pt,center]{part title}
      \usebeamerfont{part title}\insertpart\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{centering}
}

\defbeamertemplate{part page}{mine}[1][]{%
  \begin{centering}
    {\usebeamerfont{part name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{part name}#1}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{part title}
      \usebeamerfont{part title}\insertpart\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{centering}
}

\defbeamertemplate{section page}{mine}[1][]{%
  \begin{centering}
    {\usebeamerfont{section name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section name}#1}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{part title}
      \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{centering}
}

\defbeamertemplate{subsection page}{mine}[1][]{%
  \begin{centering}
    {\usebeamerfont{subsection name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection name}#1}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{part title}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection title}\insertsubsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{centering}
}

%\usecolortheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem}[ams style]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\newtheorem{remark}{\newline Remark}
\newtheorem{proposition}{\newline Proposition}

\numberwithin{section}{part}
\numberwithin{theorem}{section}

\renewcommand\thetheorem{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}
\renewcommand\thelemma{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{lemma}}
\renewcommand\theproposition{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{proposition}}
\renewcommand\thedefinition{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{definition}}
\renewcommand\theproposition{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{proposition}}
\renewcommand\theremark{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{remark}}
\renewcommand\theexample{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{example}}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{theorem}{section}
\@addtoreset{remark}{section}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{stepenumerate}{\begin{enumerate}[<+->]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemize}{\begin{itemize}[<+->]}{\end{itemize} }
\newenvironment{stepenumeratewithalert}{\begin{enumerate}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemizewithalert}{\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{itemize} }

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
\def\stackunder#1#2{\mathrel{\mathop{#2}\limits_{#1}}}

\undef{\lemma}
\undef{\example}
\newtheorem{lemma}{\translate{Lemma}}
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{\translate{Example}}[section]

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{part page}[mine][Part 1]
\part{\bf A beautiful mind}

\begin{frame}[label=Part1]
This is the content of Part \ref{Part1} and should be printed as \textbf{'Part 1'}.
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{part page}[mine][]
\part{Introduction}

\begin{frame}
This is the Introduction and has no reference.
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{part page}[mine][Chapter 1]
\part{THE FIRST CHAPTER IN THE PRESENTATION}\label{Chapter1}

\begin{frame}
This is Chapter \ref{Chapter1} and should be printed as \textbf{'Chapter 1'}.
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}[mine][]
\section{1.1 The first section in Chapter 1}\label{Section1.1}

\begin{frame}
This is Section \ref{Section1.1} and should be printed as \textbf{'Section 1.1'}.
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}[]
\section{1.2 The second section in Chapter 1}\label{Section1.2}

\begin{frame}
This is Section \ref{Section1.2} and should be printed as \textbf{'Section 1.2'}.
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{part page}[mine][Chapter 2]
\part{THE SECOND CHAPTER IN THE PRESENTATION}\label{Chapter2}
\setcounter{part}{2}

\begin{frame}
This is Chapter \ref{Chapter2} and should be printed as \textbf{'Chapter 2'}.
\end{frame}

\section{2.1 The first section in Chapter 2}\label{Section2.1}

\begin{frame}
This is Section \ref{Section2.1} and should be printed as \textbf{'Section 2.1'}.
\end{frame}

\subsection{The first subsection in Section 2.1}\label{Subsection2.1.1}

\begin{frame}
This is Subsection \ref{Subsection2.1.1} and should be printed as \textbf{'Subsection 2.1.1'}.
\end{frame}

\subsection{The second subsection in Section 2.1}\label{Subsection2.1.2}

\begin{frame}
This is Subsection \ref{Subsection2.1.2} and should be printed as \textbf{'Subsection 2.1.2'}.
\end{frame}

\section{2.2 The second section in Chapter 2}\label{Section2.2}

\begin{frame}
This is Section \ref{Section2.2} and should be printed as \textbf{'Section 2.2'}.
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{part page}[mine][Part 2]
\part{\bf Life Is Beautiful}\label{Part2}

\begin{frame}
This is Part \ref{Part2} and should be referenced as \textbf{'Part 2'}.
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{part page}[mine][Part 3]
\part{\bf Pulp Fiction}\label{Part3}

\begin{frame}
This is Part \ref{Part3} and should be referenced as \textbf{'Part 3'}.
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{part page}[mine][Part 4]
\part{\bf Forrest Gump}\label{Part4}

\begin{frame}
This is Part \ref{Part4} and should be referenced as \textbf{'Part 4'}.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that they not printed properly, e.g., Part 1 is printed as Part 2, Chapter 1 as Chapter 3, Section 1.1 as Section 3.1, Section 1.2 as Section 3.2, Chapter 2 as Chapter 4, Subsection 2.1.1 as Subsection 1, Subsection 2.1.2 as Subsection 2, Part 2 as Part 3, Part 3 as Part 4, Part 4 as Part 5. Only Sections 2.1 and 2.2 are referenced correctly (see the printscreens attached).

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `\begin{frame}[label=Part1]` the label will point to the frame, not the part.

If you want to label the part, place `\label{Part1}` after the `\part{...}` command.

---

Using the same sectioning level for both parts and "chapter" is a guarantee for chaos.

Start with a top level, e.g. parts and then move down from there. For your "chapters", you should use sections, for your sections use subsections etc.

---

---

Some other comments:

- no need to load xcolor, amssymb, amsbsy, amsthm, amsfonts, amsmath and etoolbox, beamer loads them for you
- beamer does not have a floating mechanism, the package placeins and float don't really make sense,
  latexsym,amsxtra,
- you shouldn't use two letter font commands like `\bf`. Also manually changing the formatting in each part title is bad style. You can instead simply use `\setbeamerfont{part title}{series=\bfseries}`

```
\documentclass[envcountsect,10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{chngcntr,
%xcolor,
bbm,
%placeins,float,
latexsym,amsxtra,
%amssymb,amsbsy,amsthm,
amscd,
%amsfonts,amsmath,
subcaption}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{figure}{section}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}

\usetheme{Antibes}
\AtBeginPart{\frame{\partpage}}
\AtBeginSection{\frame{\sectionpage}}
\AtBeginSubsection{\frame{\subsectionpage}}

\setbeamertemplate{part page}
{
  \begin{centering}
    {\usebeamerfont{part name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{part name}\partname~\insertpartnumber}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=16pt,center]{part title}
      \usebeamerfont{part title}\insertpart\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{centering}
}

\defbeamertemplate{part page}{mine}[1][]{%
  \begin{centering}
    {\usebeamerfont{part name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{part name}#1}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{part title}
      \usebeamerfont{part title}\insertpart\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{centering}
}

\defbeamertemplate{section page}{mine}[1][]{%
  \begin{centering}
    {\usebeamerfont{section name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section name}#1}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{part title}
      \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{centering}
}

\defbeamertemplate{subsection page}{mine}[1][]{%
  \begin{centering}
    {\usebeamerfont{subsection name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection name}#1}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{part title}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection title}\insertsubsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{centering}
}

%\usecolortheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem}[ams style]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\newtheorem{remark}{\newline Remark}
\newtheorem{proposition}{\newline Proposition}

\numberwithin{section}{part}
\numberwithin{theorem}{section}

\numberwithin{subsection}{section}

\renewcommand\thetheorem{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}
\renewcommand\thelemma{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{lemma}}
\renewcommand\theproposition{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{proposition}}
\renewcommand\thedefinition{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{definition}}
\renewcommand\theproposition{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{proposition}}
\renewcommand\theremark{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{remark}}
\renewcommand\theexample{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{example}}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{theorem}{section}
\@addtoreset{remark}{section}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{stepenumerate}{\begin{enumerate}[<+->]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemize}{\begin{itemize}[<+->]}{\end{itemize} }
\newenvironment{stepenumeratewithalert}{\begin{enumerate}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemizewithalert}{\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{itemize} }

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
\def\stackunder#1#2{\mathrel{\mathop{#2}\limits_{#1}}}

\undef{\lemma}
\undef{\example}
\newtheorem{lemma}{\translate{Lemma}}
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{\translate{Example}}[section]

\setbeamerfont{part title}{series=\bfseries}

\newcounter{storepart}

\begin{document}

\part{A beautiful mind}
\label{Part1}

\begin{frame}
This is the content of Part \ref{Part1} and should be printed as \textbf{'Part 1'}.
\end{frame}

\part{Introduction}
\addtocounter{part}{-1}

\begin{frame}
This is the Introduction and has no reference.
\end{frame}

\setcounter{storepart}{\thepart}
\setcounter{part}{0}
\setbeamertemplate{part page}[mine][Chapter 1]
\part{THE FIRST CHAPTER IN THE PRESENTATION}\label{Chapter1}

\begin{frame}
This is Chapter \ref{Chapter1} and should be printed as \textbf{'Chapter 1'}.
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}[mine][]
\section{1.1 The first section in Chapter 1}\label{Section1.1}

\begin{frame}
This is Section \ref{Section1.1} and should be printed as \textbf{'Section 1.1'}.
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}[]
\section{1.2 The second section in Chapter 1}\label{Section1.2}

\begin{frame}
This is Section \ref{Section1.2} and should be printed as \textbf{'Section 1.2'}.
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{part page}[mine][Chapter 2]
\part{THE SECOND CHAPTER IN THE PRESENTATION}\label{Chapter2}
\setcounter{part}{2}

\begin{frame}
This is Chapter \ref{Chapter2} and should be printed as \textbf{'Chapter 2'}.
\end{frame}

\section{2.1 The first section in Chapter 2}\label{Section2.1}

\begin{frame}
This is Section \ref{Section2.1} and should be printed as \textbf{'Section 2.1'}.
\end{frame}

\subsection{The first subsection in Section 2.1}\label{Subsection2.1.1}

\begin{frame}
This is Subsection \ref{Subsection2.1.1} and should be printed as \textbf{'Subsection 2.1.1'}.
\end{frame}

\subsection{The second subsection in Section 2.1}\label{Subsection2.1.2}

\begin{frame}
This is Subsection \ref{Subsection2.1.2} and should be printed as \textbf{'Subsection 2.1.2'}.
\end{frame}

\section{2.2 The second section in Chapter 2}\label{Section2.2}

\begin{frame}
This is Section \ref{Section2.2} and should be printed as \textbf{'Section 2.2'}.
\end{frame}

\setcounter{part}{\thestorepart}
\setbeamertemplate{part page}[mine][Part 2]
\part{Life Is Beautiful}\label{Part2}

\begin{frame}
This is Part \ref{Part2} and should be referenced as \textbf{'Part 2'}. 
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{part page}[mine][Part 3]
\part{Pulp Fiction}\label{Part3}

\begin{frame}
This is Part \ref{Part3} and should be referenced as \textbf{'Part 3'}.
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{part page}[mine][Part 4]
\part{Forrest Gump}\label{Part4}

\begin{frame}
This is Part \ref{Part4} and should be referenced as \textbf{'Part 4'}.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and comments. The lack of 'chapter' in 'beamer' caused problems even with the numbering of the parts, sections, subsections. I will take into account your remarks.

Comment: How can I add tableofcontents in this beamer presentation?

Comment: @NurAlam If you have a new question, please use the "Ask Question" button on the top right